# Audio getting played multiple times using MediaPlayer

Tags: android-mediaplayer

Trying to write a program in which on click of listItem want to play specific audio from raw.  But every click play without stopping previous track.

```
package com.vaishnavismeclass.tiruppavai;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    Context c = getApplicationContext();
    public static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(new VcAdapter(this));
        // 
        // to handle onclicklistener
        //
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position ["+position+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 //Uri pasuram01 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pasuram01);
                 //Uri pasuram02 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pasuram02);
                 //int resID = 0;

                 playMyMusic(position, mp);


                }





        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void playMyMusic(int songNumber, MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        //
        //
        // assign the music
        //
        //
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position for play is  ["+songNumber+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (songNumber) {
        case 0:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.taniyan01);
            //mp.start();
            break;
        case 1:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.taniyan02);
            //mp.start();
            break;
        case 2:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.taniyan03);
            //mp.start();
            break;
        case 3:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pasuram01);
            ;
            break;
        case 4:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pasuram02);
            ;
            break;
        }


            //mp.prepare();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Playing  ["+songNumber+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Player is playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
            }
            else
            {

                mp.start();
            }

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Played  ["+songNumber+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}

class SingleRow {
    String pasuram;
    int img;

    SingleRow(String pasuram, int img) {
        this.pasuram = pasuram;
        this.img = img;
    }
}

class VcAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;

    VcAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
        list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
        // get resources using context
        Resources res = c.getResources();
        String[] pasuram_en = res.getStringArray(R.array.pasurams_ta);
        //String[] pasuram_ta = res.getStringArray(R.array.pasurams_ta);
        //String[] pasuram_te = res.getStringArray(R.array.pasurams_te);
        int[] imgs = { R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p1,
                R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p2, R.drawable.p3, R.drawable.p4,
                R.drawable.p5, R.drawable.p6, R.drawable.p7, R.drawable.p8,
                R.drawable.p9, R.drawable.p10, R.drawable.p11, R.drawable.p12,
                R.drawable.p13, R.drawable.p14, R.drawable.p15, R.drawable.p16,
                R.drawable.p17, R.drawable.p18, R.drawable.p19, R.drawable.p20,
                R.drawable.p21, R.drawable.p22, R.drawable.p23, R.drawable.p24,
                R.drawable.p25, R.drawable.p26, R.drawable.p27, R.drawable.p28,
                R.drawable.p29, R.drawable.p30, R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

        for (int i = 0; i < pasuram_en.length; i++) {
            // list.add(new SingleRow(pasuram_en[i], imgs[i]));
            list.add(new SingleRow(pasuram_en[i], imgs[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);

        TextView pasuram = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);
        pasuram.setText(temp.pasuram);
        img.setImageResource(temp.img);

        return row;
    }

}
```

MediaPlayer.IsPlaying() is returning false even though audio is currently played.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Above code works, but multiple audio are being played.  Would like only one instance play when user click on the list item.  any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

declare MediaPlayer as static.

```
public static MediaPlayer mp;
```

Comment: Tried, but same issue continues.

Comment: let me know what the issue is?

Comment: Each click on the listitem creates a instance of mediaplayer.  Mediaplayer.isPlaying() is not getting recognized.

Comment: are you still using the statement as MediaPlayer mp = new MediayaPlayer(); then remove the "new MediayaPlayer()" section from the line,

Comment: Updated the code, but without initialization with new mediaPlayer(), code does not work.  Getting error "stop called in state 1".  Current state is multiple instances are still getting playing.

Comment: also change if (mp.isPlaying()) to if (mp!=null && mp.isPlaying())

Comment: if (mp!=null) returns what?